# How to handle history.pushState with content change

Tags: javascript, browser-history

While Mozilla has an [easy to understand documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history) on `history.pushState` and `history.replaceState` it doesn't show me how to deal with the content when the back button is pressed and content is changed dynamically.

Suppose foo.html has a form and executes an AJAX call to replace its content on submit, then pushState looks like below:

```
history.pushState({content:$('#content').html()}, '', 'bar.html');
```

When the user clicks on the back button the URL changes back to foo.html but the page doesn't display the form. How can I display the form? I had a look at popState but couldn't get it to work properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store all of the state you need to re-render the old content, then use that state to re-create the previous page on `popstate`.

Model-binding techniques such as Knockout.js (or full MVC frameworks) can make this much easier.

Answer (score 2):

so this is what I have done to solve it:

When foo.html loads, I execute `history.replaceState({container:$(#container').html()},'', window.location);`

Then after ajax call to replace content, I execute this: `history.pushState({container:$(#container').html()},'', 'bar.html');`

On page load, I bind the popstate to check if event has state object which contains the container like this:

```
$(window).bind("popstate", function(event) {
    if (event.state != null){
        if ('container' in event.state){
            $(#container').html(event.state.container);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: This will break all non-`live` event handlers.

Comment: ha yeah, thanks for the heads up, all my events are "live" bindings in this case.